# Identifying from a List of Lists Recursively

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

currently learning about logic in computing as well as the foundations of Prolog. Please bear with me in my fumbling speech!

I've been faced with a problem where, given an query of a list of lists containing integers, one must devise a way to calculate the highest sum of all the lists using recursion.

For example:

```
?- getSum([[1,3,6],[9,5,2],[3,4,7]], X).
X = 16.
```

Should be the output.

I believe the correct way to find the sum of a list is:

```
sum([],0).
sum([Head|Body], Output) :- sum(Body, BodySum),
   Output is Head + BodySum.
```

However I need to compare the sums before displaying the result, do I have to call to another conditional inside the sum recursion?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Several comments first:

**Naming**: you probably want to name your predicate so that it is obvious what it does. And, Prolog prefers `names_like_this` to `namesInCamelCase`. So maybe, call it `max_sublist_sum`, maybe?

**Implementation**: in your question you say, "using recursion". *Must* you use recursion, or do you think that using recursion is your only choice? Since this is a trivial problem, it can be solved using library predicates and avoiding recursion altogether. For example, to find the sums of each sub-list:

```
maplist(sum_list, List_of_lists, Sums)
```

Now you have reduced your list of lists to a list of sums. You can find the largest of a list of numbers:

```
max_list(List_of_numbers, Max_number)
```

So, your problem becomes:

```
?- maplist(sum_list, [[1,3,6],[9,5,2],[3,4,7]], Sums),
   max_list(Sums, Max_sum).
Sums = [10, 16, 14],
Max_sum = 16.
```

Now, it may seem as a good exercise to implement each of `sum_list/2` and `max_list/2`, but a good starting point would be to look at the [library implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/lists.pl?show=src) of these two. Same goes for the [definition of `maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#maplist/3)

You can also intertwine the two:

```
max_sublist_sum0([H|T], Max) :-
    sum_list(H, Sum),
    max_sublist_sum0_(T, Sum, Max).
max_sublist_sum0_([], Max, Max).
max_sublist_sum0_([H|T], M0, Max) :-
    sum_list(H, Sum),
    (   Sum > M0
    ->  max_sublist_sum0_(T, Sum, Max)
    ;   max_sublist_sum0_(T, M0, Max)
    ).
```

The helper predicate `max_sublist_sum_/3` is in practice a fold:

```
max_sum(L, M0, M) :-
    sum_list(L, Sum),
    M is max(M0, Sum).

max_sublist_sum1([H|T], Max) :-
    sum_list(H, Sum),
    foldl(max_sum, T, Sum, Max).
```

However, this is still much more code than the original suggestion:

```
max_sublist_sum(L, M) :-
    maplist(list_sum, L, S),
    max_list(S, M).
```

Interestingly, on my computer this last version is also fastest for somewhat larger lists, and takes about the same time as the faster of the other two.

Comment: You referred to the runtime of different code versions... how big is that timing difference? And what was the size of the problem?

Comment: Why not use a goal like `M1 is max(M0,Sum)`?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call another condition inside the recursion, you have to decompose the problem into calculating the sum and the maximum. Following a classic implementation of a `max` predicate, where the second argument is the current maximum, this would be something like:

```
max([], X, X).
max([H|T], X, Y) :-
  sum(H, S),
  S < X,
  max(T, X, Y).
max([H|T], X, Y) :-
  sum(H, S),
  S >= X,
  max(T, S, Y).

getSum(L, X) :- max(L, 0, X).
```

You could make this code more efficient and elegant by using an if-construct or a cut, I leave this to you.

Comment: What's the result of, `getSum([[-1,-2],[-3,-4]], S).` and is it correct?

Comment: Admittedly did not handle negative numbers. Caveat Emptor. The question was about recursion, not "solve my homework".

Comment: Understood. It's just a little off from the "classic implementation of a max predicate". ;)

Comment: This will execute `sum(H,S)` twice. Always.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you have two conditionals for the value of S when you still call the max predicate regardless? Any valid query returns "false" instead of a sum, so there seems to be a logical error..

Comment: Calling `sum` twice is not mandatory. This code can be simplified using a cut, if-statement or some other smart layout. I was trying to demonstrate a different decomposition of the problem, not solve the guy's assignment.

Comment: There are many ways to decide what is the largest element of a list, but seeding with a randomly chosen initial value is just plain wrong... At least use the first element for the seed. Otherwise, your answer is more confusing than anything.